# symfony problem with embedI18n

Tags: php, internationalization, symfony1

i'm really stuck with this. I have to create a dynamic multilanguage form, and doing it like this:

```
class TreeForm extends BaseTreeForm
{
    public function configure()
    {
        parent::configure();
        [...]
        $languages = sfConfig::get('app_language_list');
        $supportedlangs = $this->getObject()->getSupLangs();
        if (empty($supportedlangs))
        {
            $supportedlangs = $languages;
        }

        $this->embedI18n($supportedlangs);

        foreach ($supportedlangs as $lang)
        {
            $this->widgetSchema->setLabel($lang, $i18n->__($lang));
        }
var_dump(array_keys($this->getEmbeddedForms()));
    }
}

class treeActions extends autoTreeActions
{
    public function executeEdit(sfWebRequest $request)
    {
        $this->tree = $this->getRoute()->getObject();
echo "action::edit->before getform():<br/>\n";
        $this->form = $this->configuration->getForm($this->tree);
echo "action::edit->after getform():<br/>\n";
var_dump(array_keys($this->form->getEmbeddedForms()));
    }
}
```

I thought this should do the trick, but the output is like this:

action::edit->before getform():
array
  0 => string 'seuzo_szolg_addresses' (length=21)
  1 => string 'hu' (length=2)
  2 => string 'en' (length=2)

action::edit->after getform():
array
  0 => string 'seuzo_szolg_addresses' (length=21)

What the crap makes my i18n embedded forms disappear just after the main form is initializaed? Any help really appreciated.

Comment: oh, I forgot to mention it's symfony 1.2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know why this doesn't work, but found a workaround:

instead of

```
$this->form = $this->configuration->getForm($this->tree);
```

I used

```
$this->form = new TreeForm($this->tree);
```

This way the embedded forms are in their place.
Hope to spare some time for someone.